# Hierarchy SQL server joining two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I'm having a problem making a hierarchy query.

I have the following in MS SQL DB:

Table A - Orders with order code, article, qty:

```
OP | ART  | QTY

A  |   X  |100
B  |   Y  |200
```

Table B with assembly references of articles, but articles CAN be made from other articles if there exist a child's reference (may need to go 3 levels deep):

```
ART | ART2 |QTY

X   |  U   | 20
X   |  O   | 10
X   |  Z   | 30
Y   |  Q   | 20
Y   |  W   | 15
Y   |  E   | 30
U   |  Z   | 10
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
A.OP  |LEVEL|  ART | B.ART2   |QTY 
A     | 2   | X    | Z        |(100*20*10)=2000
A     | 1   | X    | O        |(100*10) =1000
A     | 1   | X    | Z        |(100*30) = 3000
B     | 1   | Y    | Q        |(200*20) = 4000
B     | 1   | Y    | W        |(200*15) = 3000
B     | 1   | Y    | E        |(200*30) = 6000
B     | 1   | Y    | Z        |(200*10) = 2000
```

I've already made one thing:

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT 
firstlvl.ART,
1 AS LEVEL,
firstlvl.ART2,
firstlvl.QTY,
QTY AS PARENTQTY
FROM B AS firstlvl
WHERE firstlvl.ART='X' 
UNION ALL
SELECT secondlevel.ART,
EL.LEVEL +1,
secondlevel.BDT_MLC,
secondlevel.ART2,
secondlevel.QTY,
EL.PARENTQTY AS PARENTQTY
FROM B AS secondlevel
INNER JOIN X AS EL
ON secondlevel.ART = EL.ART2)
SELECT * FROM X
```

But now I don't know how to join quantities with table A nor how to run this query for all items on the first table.

Can anyone help me please?

Many Thanks!

Comment: To make it easier for responders please make an SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with AllData as 
( select op as art, art as art2, qty from a
 union all
  select * from b),
Tree(RootLvl, Father, Child, qty, lvl) as (
select art, art, art2, qty, 0  from AllData 
where art in ( 'A' , 'B')
union all
select C.RootLvl, C.Child, AllData.art2, AllData.qty * c.qty, C.lvl + 1 from Tree C 
join AllData 
on C.Child = AllData.art
 )
 select C1.RootLvl as OP, C1.Lvl, C1.Child, C1.Qty from Tree c1 
 left join Tree  c2
 on c1.child = c2.father and
    c1.rootLvl = c2.RootLvl
 where C2.RootLvl is null
 order by 1, 2 desc
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b9fdf/1/0)

The A and B tables are almost the same. I made one from them to just simplify it. After that we use recursion to create tree and at the end I use left join to get only leafs from tree.